# Display a JSP page from a URL in a modal popup in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp, angularjs-ng-include

I am trying to load a JSP page inside a modal in AngularJS.

The JSP page have lot of scripts and so I wont be able to take the source and create a separate template. The URL is from a different server but I have CORS enabled in my server. Is there someway we can include the file in a div using `ng-include src=""`? I already tried this but it is not working. Can anyone recommend a solution?

Comment: Can you explain why I was downvoted so that I can make the improvement?

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing a valid code the code should be like this:

```
<div ng-include="'file path'"></div>
```

Note: Make sure of single inverted comma within double inverted comma. And file path can be of your any absolute path. Do not write src while using ng-include.

Comment: But the JSP I am trying to include is not a local file. It is in a different server (https://g****s.com/som/staticText.lvp?dialogContentType=5). I want a solution to take the template from the URL and then show it in a div.

Comment: Have you tried this exact url ? (https://g****s.com/som/staticText.lvp?dialogContentType=5) in my code

Comment: yes its not working. Thats why I tried ng-include src format which didnt work as well.

Comment: Probability 1
I think you are trying to access some application session page so it will not allow to load that page.

Probability 2
Or you try to run your application on local absolute path am assuming that you are not using any server on your local machine because ng-include works on server only.

Comment: I am trying to access the page on a different server. Suppose I want to display "www.google.com" inside a div in my angular application, how will i achieve that? That is what I am trying to ask.

Comment: Finally i understood the problem you need to set the header.
To allow this file to be read from other domains, it must contain the header to be: 
access-control-allow-origin:*

This settings would be done on the server side where you wish to access the path.

like:

<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
?>

Comment: Okay so I need to add the URL in header and then include it in the HTML using ng-include?